# How can check if a field is empty in a node template?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I am using Drupal 8. I have a paragraphs field (field type: paragraphs of reference revisions) in node template, I tried lots of ways to check if the field is empty (purpose is to show the field only it has a value).

```
<code>
{# Below codes in node.html.twig #}
{# Below codes NOT work #}
  {% if content.field_notes.0 is empty %}
    This field is empty-1.
  {% endif %}

  {% if content.field_notes[0] is empty %}
    This field is empty-2.
  {% endif %}

  {# Enable module:twig field value #}
  {% if content.field_notes|field_value is empty %}
    This field is empty-3.
  {% endif %}

  {% if node.field_notes.isempty %}
    This field is empty-4.
  {% endif %}

  {% if node.field_notes.value is empty %}
    This field is empty-5.
  {% endif %}
</code>
```

How can check if a paragraphs field is empty in node template in Drupal 8?

**UPDATE:**
Codes tested and result below, the way NOT work for paragraphs but work for some other field types.

`{% set count_field_element_1 = node.field_paragraphs|length %}
  {{ count_field_element_1 }}
  {# when field has or no value: count_field_element_1 = 2 #}
  {# paragraphs type contains two field type: image and text plain long #}`

{% set count_field_element_2 = node.field_image|length %}
  {{ count_field_element_2 }}
  {# when field has value: count_field_element_2 = 1; #}
  {# when field has no value: count_field_element_2 = 0; #}

{% set count_field_element_3 = node.field_text_plain_long|length %}
  {{ count_field_element_3 }}
  {# when field has value: count_field_element_3 = 1; #}
  {# when field has no value: count_field_element_3 = 0; #}

Maybe my question is not very clear, let me explain more as below:
The purpose of this question is to check if paragraphs field (not other field types) has a value. When a field value is input and saved, node page will show the field and its value; when no field value is input and saved, node page will NOT show the field (including the div element).

`{% set count_field_element = node.field_paragraphs|length %}
  {{ count_field_element }}`

**count_field_element is 1 for below:**
[image]

**count_field_element is 0 for below(removing all form items of paragraphs in node form):**
[image]

In short, up till now, I still NOT figure out a way to check if a paragraphs field has a value, node page will show paragraphs field empty only when removing all form items of paragraphs in node form.

Answer (score 3):

Check on `node.field_notes` something like

```
 {% set count_paragraph_element = node.field_notes | length %}
  {% if count_paragraph_element == 0 %}
      Empty
  {% else %}
      Not empty
  {% endif %}
```

**Update**
if you want to check if `text plain long` field has empty value try this.
I assume that your field machine name is `field_text`:

```
{% for item in node.field_notes %}
      {% if item.entity.field_text.value is empty %}
        text value is empty
      {% else %}
        text value not empty
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi berramou, please see my update above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about just `node.field_name is empty`?

Comment: Hi Kevin, {% if node.field_paragraphs is empty %} not work for paragraphs.

Comment: `node.field_name` gives you a liste of item of the entity types, in this case something like `EntityReferenceRevisionsFieldItemList {#1396 ▼
  #list: []
  #langcode: "en"
  #definition: FieldConfig {#967 ▶}
  #name: "field_paragraph"
  #parent: EntityAdapter {#942 ▶}
  #stringTranslation: null
  #typedDataManager: TypedDataManager {#613 ▶}
}`   so the `node.field_name` always not empty.

Comment: i have tested it works for me with field of type paragraph. i get `count_paragraph_element` equal 0 when the field is empty, and number of items if its not.

Comment: I have tested, node show the field paragraphs empty only when removing all items of this paragraphs in node form (no form item, just show 'no paragraphs added yet').